# Что такое CL в DDR4?

Tags: память, железо

Какая скорость оперативной памяти сегодня? CL - CAS Latency - задержка при CAS... для профи может что-то говорит. Только... почему чем выше скорость оперативки тем выше CL? Мне казалось что должно быть наоборот.

Открываю любую попавшуюся ddr4 не нашел даташит, например для ddr3 вот http://www.icsi.com.tw/pdf/43TR16256A-85120AL.pdf читаю  - 13 наносекунд - т.е. около 66МНz, т.е. сама память 1866МНz, а что тут делает 13 наносекунд? Т.е. это невыравняное обращение в 100 раз более медленное? Для DDR4 тоже стало непонятно CL14 - задержка на 14 наносекунд т.е. те же около 66МНz? Тем не менее обещают полную скорость в "Пропускная способность  19200 МБ/сек" равную 8*2400 MHz.

1. Правильно ли я понимаю, обработка cas-сигнала длится 14 нс для cl14, а ras-менее наносекунды?
2. Получается что за время одного CAS-обращение можно было бы сделать 100 RAS-обращений (100 грубо, реально 1866/71Мнz=26 но чем выше память, тем показатель выше). И если мы будем намеренно заставлять CPU в защищенном режиме перебирать данные с разных CAS-cтраниц (можно через cr3 в ОЗУ примапить физически допустим 256 страниц, с адресами специально с 256Мб интервалом, и запустить на чтение 1Гиг участок с шагом в 4096) то получим скорость памяти около 70МHz (14 нс)?
3. На сколько % CL-параметр снижает быстродействие памяти? Как я понимаю, размер страницы... 32-бита - это 4Gb, спаренные RAS-CAS дают грубо 16 бит. 2 в 16 степени равно 64К, т.е выходя за границу памяти 64Кбайт (может реально 256К-байт) приходится переключать страницу. При линеном чтении - каждые 64К операций линейного чтения прийдётся 1 раз переключить потратив... 0,1К на один CAS (для 2400 CL14). Грубо это 0,1%? А в реальности мы теряем от 1% до 10% быстродействия памяти для CL14? 2400/70МНz=34цикла Или процент потерь скорости другой?
4. Что лучше 2400МНz CL14 или 2666МНz CL17?  Как-то цифра 17 ну соовсем пугает. CL17 (58МНz) даст замедление от 1,2% до 12% в сравнении с п3? 2666/58=46 циклов.  UDP:У дорогой DDR4 3200МНz СL15 число циклов "простоя" около 55, и похоже этот показатель будет расти...

Comment: Где именно вы прочитали про 13 наносекунд ? В приведенном вами даташите написано "_The CAS Latency is defined by MR0 (bits A9-A11) as shown in Figure 2.3.2. CAS Latency is the delay, in clock cycles,
between the internal Read command and the availability of the first bit of output data._". Т.е. CAS измеряется в циклах шины памяти, а не в наносекундах.

Comment: @Mike я не эксперт здесь, но вы скорее всего не правы. Для памяти всё измеряется в наносекундах. Но тайминги указывают для определенной частоты. Вы поднимите частоту, тайминги растут. Повысили частоту - циклы стали быстрее - но и ceil((время задержки)/(время цикла)) тоже растет.

Comment: "Что лучше 2400МНz CL14 или 2666МНz CL17?" - тайминги поменяются в зависимости от реальной частоты на которой будет работать память. Насколько я понимаю, реальное значение имеет только задержка в наносекундах.

Comment: @Zergatul Да, в итоге все переводиться конечно в наносекунды. но тайминги задаются в циклах шины. Соответственно 1 тайминга на более быстрой шины короче во времени. А цифра тайминга выше, потому что операция переключения страницы по времени занимает примерно столько же

Comment: @Mike параметр CL-nRCD-nRP. Тайминги сегодня можно менять, и большинство биосов позволяет менять тайминги, в чипе есть три бита, которые могут переключать тайминги в диапазоне 2^3 = 8 вариантов тайминга. Именно через этот механизм биос физически задаёт тайминги.

Comment: К чему холливары то? В чем измеряется - написано прямо в тексте даташита(CAS Latency is the delay,**in clock cycles**), за что отвечает этот параметр - гуглится за минуту, `задержка между поступлением комманды и началом отправки данных`, т.е. CL14 - после получения комманды пройдет 14 **тактов** до начала отправки данных. и хоть заизменяйте частоты в какую хотите сторону, будет 14 неизменных тактов. а вот длительность такта во времени - будет менятся в зависимости от частоты.

Comment: 2400 CL14 CAS = (1ns/2666*14) 0,00583 ns, 2666 CL17 CAS = 0,00637 ns  Да, выходит что во втором случае время переключения выше. Только предложенный вами тест очень синтетический. Программы чаще работают со смежными областями памяти. Плюс к этому надо бы еще посчитать сколько времени занимает чтение 16 байт, меньше процессор читать за раз не будет

Comment: @Mike а теперь ставим обе указанные планки на одну шину, и видим что вторая резко стала хуже =)

Comment: 14 тактов - всё хорошо. Тогда спрошу так. Я покупая оперативку  DDR4 2400 расчитываю на скорость  19200 МБ/сек, на сколько % медленнее будет оперативка при CL=14, CL=17 ? Т.е. в реальности я увижу 2300 (18200)? Или вообще будет 2000МНz (16000)? Или вообще будет 1000МНz?

Comment: @Mike *со смежными областями памяти* - Вся память поделена на страницы. У нас допустим 4 ядра, работает 4 задачи (реально больше). Учитывая что в 64-битном режиме размер виртуальной страницы памяти 64кбайт, т.е. есть большая вероятность что две задачи будут читать данные с двух разных страниц памяти. Если обе будут ломится в оперативку - то переключений будет много.А встроеная видео - перебирает свои страницы. Так как, насколько много - мы померять не можем - то думаю в ответ подходят результаты тестов. И замедление может получится как около 1% так и около 10. До 50% надеюсь не доходит:)

Comment: Вы еще про DMA забыли, она то же будет лезть в память по той же шине. А в итоге - да, только тесты. но тесты то же могут быть не показательны. Тут как то проходил вопрос с показательными тестами что перемножение матриц 4097x4097 в разы быстрее, чем матриц 4096x4096 просто потому, что при шаге в памяти кратном 4096 все обращения идут через одну запись L3 кеша

Comment: @nick_n_a покупая оперативку DDR4 2400, вы расчитываете на скорость 19200, именно такой она и будет. и для CL14 и для CL17. Этот параметр влияет не на **скорость**, а на задержки.. 
Аналог: `У вас 100мбит канал, и при пинге 500мс и при пинге в 10мс, скорость вашего канала не изменится и будет 100мбит. но в первом случае после отправки запроса вы ответ получите через 500мс, во втором через 10мс`

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков но если я перекачиваю файл в несколько гиг - то я всёравно выйду на "реальную" скорость, которая снизится с учётом задержек. В каком %-тном соотношении эти задержки повлияют на общую скорость? В районе 0,5 процента и не беспокоиться, или можем получить 10%? От 2400  10 % это будет уже 2160.

Comment: @nick_n_a нет, задержки не влияют на скорость(влияют но не прямо), если вы будете делать много запросов мелких порций данных, больше чем может переварить ОЗУ - вы упретесь в пропускную способность и разовьете максимальную скорость, если вы будете делать мало запросов на крупные данные - вы разовьете всю скорость шины. и только если вы будете делать мало запросов на мало данных - вы упретесь в CAS а не в скорость шины.

Comment: А теперь контр пример "большому файлу" если вы одновременно на 10 разных машин будете лить много больших файлов - вы упретесь в канал а не в задержки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Правильно ли я понимаю, обработка cas-сигнала длится 14 нс для cl14, а ras-менее наносекунды?*

1) Неправильно, задержка указана в тактах шины ОЗУ(14 тактов).

2) Смешались кони, люди, Ответ на вопрос - нет, просто мешанина всего подряд в вопросе.
CAS - время на открытие колонки, RAS - время на "открытие" строки. не открыв строку вы ничего не прочтете, открыв колонку - вы можете прочитать строки. т.е. время чтения = CAS+RAS (грубо очень но думаю понятно что они не отделимы).
Сложно померить скорость в указанных вами величинах 70MHz - это что угодно но не скорость.

3) Напрямую - не снижает вообще, это не про максимальную скорость канала, а про время между запросом и ответом. Чтобы добиться максимальной скорости - необходимо либо запрашивать большие блоки либо много(накладные расходы вырастут но они тоже входят в пропускную способность канала).

> *Что лучше 2400МНz CL14 или 2666МНz CL17? Как-то цифра 17 ну соовсем пугает.*

4) Смотря что вам нужно, задержки меньше - в первом случае, но тем не менее скорость при прочих равных выше у второй.

> *CL17 (58МНz) даст замедление от 1,2% до 12% в сравнении с п3? 2666/58=46 циклов. UDP:У дорогой DDR4 3200МНz СL15 число циклов "простоя" около 55, и похоже этот показатель будет расти...*

Вот эти подсчеты выше моих сил.
CL17 означает что если вы посылаете запрос на озу, то перед первым полученым вами байтом пройдет 17тактов(+Trcd), дальше - быстрей, дальше каждый байт будет получаться по RAS. 
2666MHz ~ 46нс+RAS для получения первого байта, дальше RAS для каждого последующего.
При этом вам никто не мешает сделать несколько запросов.

Почти всё или всё что написано в этом ответе было в комментариях.
Реальные скорости на реальном железе будут далеки от теоретических которые мы вычитываем с даташитов. Далеко не всегда нужна минимальная задержка, и далеко не всегда важна большая скорость, выбирая такие вещи нужно точно понимать цель использования.

Comment: То что я неправильно интерпретировал CL я понял. Я пересчитаю показатели... для того что бы можно было сделать выводы. Из ответа не понятно нужно учитывать CL или не нужно, ответ аккурат "не вашим не нашим".

Comment: @nick_n_a, вам ответили, как и на что влияет CL, что ещё нужно-то?

Comment: @nick_n_a Ответ в 4 пункте, если вам ВАЖНЫ задержки - учитывать. **если вы собираетесь получать по 1 байту со страницы - эта задержка один из важнейших показателей**, иначе нужно считать что будет быстрей, лишние пара нс на выбор страницы или более быстрое чтение самой страницы. т.е. в отрыве от задачи - данный параметр маловажный, его невозможно посчитать не зная точной характеристики нагрузки.